# Possible to start printing on 3rd label on 2nd row with FPDF or TCPDF?

Tags: php, variables, fpdf, tcpdf

Is it possible to start printing on a particular label (set by a $_POST) value?  If I have 10 labels to a page, and I want them to start on the 3rd label (2nd label on the 2nd row), is there a way to tell either FPDF or TCPDF to do that?

Update:

This is where the class for fPDF labels comes from:
[fPDF Label Class](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script29.php)

The line of code that controls this in fPDF is:

```
function __construct($format, $unit='mm', $posX=1, $posY=1)
```

When I change the $posx=__ and the $posY=__, the labels DO start printing in different positions!

However, when I set:

```
function __construct($format, $unit='mm', $posX=$setthex, $posY=$setthey)
```

I get an error: PHP Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations

I've read about this on SO, but I'm at a loss regarding 'Static' issues...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried that isn't working as well as an example of what you have now and what the desired result is. You haven't provided any information at all that might allow someone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, kind of .. Not with these variables, but by inserting X amount of blank labels before I started printing the correct ones.